How to build the game Raptor v1.2 from the original source code release?
I got really stoked by the release of original Raptor v1.2 source code on https://github.com/skynettx/dosraptor with the blessing of the Scott Host. However, although I tried both 86Box with MS-DOS 6.22, DOSBox-X and plain old DOSBox, both TASM 2.51 (doesn't compile the files properly), 3.1 (seemingly works) and 4.1 (also seemingly works), and using both the supposedly optimal Watcom C 10.0 and also 10.0a compiler, I wasn't able to build a stable game, neither in shareware nor retail mode. The best I could get was a version that:

failed on FILE_ID.DIZ content check (even with the data files from the original game!), which I manually disabled to proceed,
with audio enabled, crashed on SND_InitSound() with a GLB_FetchItem error on STARTHELP load
with audio disabled, crashed on INTRO_Credits() with a GLB_FetchItem error on START_SFX load
with that commented out:

played garbled intro videos (probably missing the initial video frame and only displaying the later frames properly on top of random pixels, in total somewhat viewable - some assets certainly did load correctly),
then had some invalid palette transition if the intro wasn't skipped,
then opened a YES/__ dialog (a variation of YES/NO with NO not really visible or active), where YES transitions to broken version of "help"/"order info" view with no text but almost proper buttons,






from there DONE would go back to the YES/__ dialog, EXIT would appear instead of the usual PREV but do nothing and NEXT would trigger app exit, i.e. fade to dark orange and then the usual full-screen exit message.

This behaviour was consistent between the VMs/emulators. I triple-checked this with unaltered code from the source repo. I tried rebuilding and debugging the GFX module (responsible for GLB loading and menu handling), but nothing really changed. Original Raptor binary works without any problems on all the above platforms.
My binary is somewhat different than the original one - 580kB vs 400kB original, probably due to debugging symbols added. I also use external DOS/4GW exe instead of built-in one.
Note: legal shareware data is enough to see if everything works here, you can get it from https://www.classicdosgames.com/files/games/mountainking/1rap12.zip e.g.
